# Propel using where with SUBSTRING

Tags: php, sql, propel

why does this no work?

```
$allRecords = RecordsQuery::create()
->where('SUBSTR(Records.paymentTime, 1, 7) = ?', '2013-02')
->findOne(); //
var_dump($allRecords);
```

it just gives back null.
If i use this as SQL-Command it returns the right record.

Records.paymentTime is a date-field.

Sincerly.

Comment: What's the datatype of records.paymenttime?

Comment: You could try to see what SQL query is actually run: `echo RecordsQuery::create()->where('SUBSTR(Records.paymentTime, 1, 7) = ?', '2013-02')->toString();`

Comment: The uotput with toString was what i wanted. Oddly it doesn't retrieve what i want. Also i can't copy the output of toString just like this into e.g. phpMyAdmin, i need to add the cells i want to retrieve.
Output somthing like this: FROM tablename WHERE SUBSTR(payment_time, 1, 7) = XXX
I need it like this: SELECT * FROM […]